# Default DB is offline - I can't do anything

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to restore over my default DB, like I have done many times before, but now I was getting told I cant restore because it's being used in this session.  I though I'd take it offline and online again to make sure it wasn't being used.  Something somewhere interuppted things.

Now I can't log in.  I can log in to master, but still can't do anything in object explorer.   What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you can log in to the Master database, try running the following query to change your login account's default database to Master (you can change back one you restore your default DB).

USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [loginname] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO

Comment: Luckily I managed to finally remember my 'sa' password and I could use that to change my windows user's default db.  There is a more technical answer using the sqlcmd commandline app, which I will post later.  Thanks though.